# What is the correct way to define a retina media query - Chrome constantly throwing the same warning?

Tags: css, media-queries, retina

I have a pattern as background - for regular resolutions as well as for retina. If i handle it that way

```
body {
    background: image-url('ttg.png') repeat top left;
    @media  (min-resolution: 1.5dppx), (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (min-resolution: 144dpi) {
        background: image-url('ttg@2X.png') repeat top left;
        background-size: 476px 476px;
    }
}
```

or that way

```
body {
    background: image-url('ttg.png') repeat top left;
    @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (min-resolution: 144dpi) {
        background: image-url('ttg@2X.png') repeat top left;
        background-size: 476px 476px;
    }
}
```

Each time Chrome is throwing the following recommendation at me:

> Consider using ‘dppx’ units instead of ‘dpi’, as in CSS ‘dpi’ means
>   dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond
>   to the actual ‘dpi’ of a screen. In media query expression:
>   (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), not all, (min-resolution:
>   144dpi)

So what is the correct way to call those two backgrounds? Best regards Ralf